# xpath and xquery using php

Tags: php, xpath

I have following format of xml file.

```
<pages>
  <contents>
    <menu><![CDATA[menu1]]></menu>
    <texts><![CDATA[content1]]></texts>
  </contents>

  <contents>
    <menu><![CDATA[menu2]]></menu>
    <texts><![CDATA[content2]]></texts>
  </contents>

  <contents>
    <menu><![CDATA[menu3]]></menu>
    <texts><![CDATA[content3]]></texts>
  </contents>
</pages>
```

Here i want to pass a parameter with menu node value for example menu1 is passed and i want to get the texts node i.e content1 or so.

How could i do that using php/xquery.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

```
/pages/contents/menu[text()='<![CDATA[$foo]]>']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use something like this** (I don't know PHP):

```
/pages/content[menu = $foo]/texts/text()
```

**or**

```
string(/pages/content[menu = $foo]/texts)
```

where the `$foo` variable is the string value of the `menu` element whose "text" is wanted.

Comment: He is not seeking the text inside menu element. He wants the text inside `texts` element, which is the sibling of `menu`.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Thanks for making this clear -- I have modified the answer accordingly.